# Adding headers and footer in actionbar tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

Hi everyone I am working currently a view which need to have a view above the tabs of  the actionbar or more like below the action bar itself, and a fixed footer between the tabs.

But I have not find a way to make this behaviour other than adding the footer in each fragment and the view that I want below the tabs.

Is there a way to put headers(above) and footer(below) tabs using the actionbar?

PD. I am using Sherlock actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Something inbetween the Actionbar and the Actionbar tabs? AFAIK it's not possible. ABS is only used in pre HC versions. On ICS+ the default ActionBar gets used. Therefore even if you can customize the ABS Actionbar you most likely can't override the default Actionbar on ICS+.

Comment: this might call for a change of design I think I can live with it!!

Comment: @Necronet But you *could* use the ViewPagerIndicator tabs from Jake Wharton, they look almost the same as the normal Actionbar tabs. :)
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator. So  you could place a view above them